# How to remove the duplicate string from an array list.ArrayList data is coming from JSON via URL?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

This is the code snippet

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
    Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.syllabus);

    Arraylist  syllabuslist = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Results bean : world) {
        syllabuslist.add(bean.getSyllabus());
    }

    // Spinner adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, syllabuslist);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    ...
}
```

**I am displaying my data in spinner**
Previously I was doing like this

```
LinkedHashSet<String> listToSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>(syllabuslist);

//Creating Arraylist without duplicate values
final List<String> slistnew = new ArrayList<String>(listToSet);
```

*but now its not working for me.*

Comment: _but now its not working for me_ ... this comment isn't working for us, because it doesn't let us pinpoint what the actual problem is.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just check that String already exists or not before adding it to list.

```
 for (Results bean : world) {
     if(!syllabuslist.contains(bean.getSyllabus()){       
        syllabuslist.add(bean.getSyllabus());
     }
 }
```